# How can I test my web-pages on a Samsung Galaxy tablet without having the actual device?

Tags: android, cross-browser, tablet, galaxy

I would like to check if my website work and look correctly on the major tablet browsers. Unfortunately, I don't own a galaxy tab; Is there an easy-to-use emulator of some sort that I can use that will show me how the site looks, including the virtual keyboard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simple. You can use Samsung Galaxy Tab add-on, which has device emulator. [Look here](http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/galaxyTab.do)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Android SDK to emulate Android. It's available for download from http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html. Typically, it's easier to use with Eclipse, but it is possible to run it from the command line. Even though you won't be doing any programming, I still recommend downloading and installing Eclipse.

In Eclipse, create a new target for FroYo and make the screen resolution 1024 × 600. Launch it (you may need to make a dummy application, but once it's made you can press the home button to exit it) and it will open up an Android emulator with the same screen resolution as the Tab.

Answer (score 1):

Samsung provides an emulator for their tablet.

Open AVD and add an add-on site with the URL: http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/android/repository/repository.xml

Comment: This link is no longer valid.

Comment: This tablet is also no longer valid.